# How could I solve this JS animation issue?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm animating around 300 colliding balls on javascript inside of an HTML canvas... code should be alright but I don't understand the reason for some strange behavior between balls crushing with each other, that sometimes appear to get stuck, lag a bit, and don't behave exactly as they should. Collisions are managed with functions ballCollision(), wallCollision() and staticCollision():

```js
class Ball {
    
    constructor(x, y, dx, dy, radius, color){
        this.radius = radius;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;

        // mass is that of a sphere as opposed to circle
        // it *does* make a difference in how realistic it looks
        this.mass = this.radius * this.radius * this.radius;
        this.color = color;
    };    

    draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(Math.round(this.x), Math.round(this.y), this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fill();
       // ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    };

    speed() {
        // magnitude of velocity vector
        return Math.sqrt(this.dx * this.dx + this.dy * this.dy);
    };
    angle() {
        // velocity's angle with the x axis
        return Math.atan2(this.dy, this.dx);
    };
    onGround() {
        return (this.y + this.radius >= canvas.height)
    };
};

//FUNCTIONS

//will remove
function randomColor() {
    let red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) * 127;
    let green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) * 127;
    let blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) * 127;

    // dim down the small balls
    if (!bigBalls){
        red *= 0.65
        green *= 0.65
        blue *= 0.65
    }

    let rc = "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")";
    return rc;
}

function randomX() {
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
    if (x < 30) {
        x = 30;
    } else if (x + 30 > canvas.width) {
        x = canvas.width - 30;
    }
    return x;
}

function randomY() {
    let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
    if (y < 30) {
        y = 30;
    } else if (y + 30 > canvas.height) {
        y = canvas.height - 30;
    }
    return y;
}

//will remove
function randomRadius() {
    if (bigBalls) {
        let r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 + 20);
        return r;
    } else {
        let r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2 + 2);
        //let r = 5;
        return r;
    }
}

//will remove
function randomDx() {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 - 4);
    return r;
}

//will remove
function randomDy() {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 - 3);
    return r;
}

function distanceNextFrame(a, b) {
    return Math.sqrt((a.x + a.dx - b.x - b.dx)**2 + (a.y + a.dy - b.y - b.dy)**2) - a.radius - b.radius;
}

function distance(a, b) {
    return Math.sqrt((a.x - b.x)**2 + (a.y - b.y)**2);
}

let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let objArray = [];
let probArray = [];
let paused = false;
let bumped = false;

let leftHeld = false;
let upHeld = false;
let rightHeld = false;
let downHeld = false;
let arrowControlSpeed = .25;

let gravityOn = false;

let clearCanv = true;

let bigBalls = false;

let lastTime = (new Date()).getTime();
let currentTime = 0;
let dt = 0;

let numStartingSmallBalls = 500;
let numStartingBigBalls = 0;

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler);

function clearCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function keyDownHandler(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 80) { // p
        paused = !paused;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 82) { // r
        objArray = [];
    } else if (event.keyCode == 75) { // k
        clearCanv = !clearCanv;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 88) { // x
        bigBalls = !bigBalls;
    }
}



function canvasBackground() {
    canvas.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(215, 235, 240)";
}

function wallCollision(ball) {
    if (ball.x - ball.radius + ball.dx < 0 ||
        ball.x + ball.radius + ball.dx > canvas.width) {
        ball.dx *= -1;
    }
    if (ball.y - ball.radius + ball.dy < 0 ||
        ball.y + ball.radius + ball.dy > canvas.height) {
        ball.dy *= -1;
    }
    if (ball.y + ball.radius > canvas.height) {
        ball.y = canvas.height - ball.radius;
    }
    if (ball.y - ball.radius < 0) {
        ball.y = ball.radius;
    }
    if (ball.x + ball.radius > canvas.width) {
        ball.x = canvas.width - ball.radius;
    }
    if (ball.x - ball.radius < 0) {
        ball.x = ball.radius;
    }    
}

function ballCollision() {
    for (let i=0; i<objArray.length-1; i++) {
        for (let j=i+1; j<objArray.length; j++) {
            let ob1 = objArray[i]
            let ob2 = objArray[j]
            let dist = distance(ob1, ob2)

            if (dist < ob1.radius + ob2.radius) {              
                let theta1 = ob1.angle();
                let theta2 = ob2.angle();
                let phi = Math.atan2(ob2.y - ob1.y, ob2.x - ob1.x);
                let m1 = ob1.mass;
                let m2 = ob2.mass;
                let v1 = ob1.speed();
                let v2 = ob2.speed();

                let dx1F = (v1 * Math.cos(theta1 - phi) * (m1-m2) + 2*m2*v2*Math.cos(theta2 - phi)) / (m1+m2) * Math.cos(phi) + v1*Math.sin(theta1-phi) * Math.cos(phi+Math.PI/2);
                let dy1F = (v1 * Math.cos(theta1 - phi) * (m1-m2) + 2*m2*v2*Math.cos(theta2 - phi)) / (m1+m2) * Math.sin(phi) + v1*Math.sin(theta1-phi) * Math.sin(phi+Math.PI/2);
                let dx2F = (v2 * Math.cos(theta2 - phi) * (m2-m1) + 2*m1*v1*Math.cos(theta1 - phi)) / (m1+m2) * Math.cos(phi) + v2*Math.sin(theta2-phi) * Math.cos(phi+Math.PI/2);
                let dy2F = (v2 * Math.cos(theta2 - phi) * (m2-m1) + 2*m1*v1*Math.cos(theta1 - phi)) / (m1+m2) * Math.sin(phi) + v2*Math.sin(theta2-phi) * Math.sin(phi+Math.PI/2);

                ob1.dx = dx1F;                
                ob1.dy = dy1F;                
                ob2.dx = dx2F;                
                ob2.dy = dy2F;

                if(ob1.speed() * 160 < 400)
                    ob1.color = 'lightblue';
                else if(ob1.speed() * 160 > 800)
                    ob1.color = 'red';
                else
                    ob1.color = 'orange';

                if(ob2.speed() * 160 < 400)
                    ob2.color = 'lightblue';
                else if(ob2.speed() * 160 > 800)
                    ob2.color = 'red';
                else
                    ob2.color = 'orange';
          
                staticCollision(ob1, ob2);
                
            }            
        }
        wallCollision(objArray[i]);
    }

    if (objArray.length > 0)
        wallCollision(objArray[objArray.length - 1])
}

function staticCollision(ob1, ob2, emergency = false)
{
    let overlap = ob1.radius + ob2.radius - distance(ob1, ob2);
    let smallerObject = ob1.radius < ob2.radius ? ob1 : ob2;
    let biggerObject = ob1.radius > ob2.radius ? ob1 : ob2;

    // When things go normally, this line does not execute.
    // "Emergency" is when staticCollision has run, but the collision
    // still hasn't been resolved. Which implies that one of the objects
    // is likely being jammed against a corner, so we must now move the OTHER one instead.
    // in other words: this line basically swaps the "little guy" role, because
    // the actual little guy can't be moved away due to being blocked by the wall.
    if (emergency) [smallerObject, biggerObject] = [biggerObject, smallerObject]
    
    let theta = Math.atan2((biggerObject.y - smallerObject.y), (biggerObject.x - smallerObject.x));
    smallerObject.x -= overlap * Math.cos(theta);
    smallerObject.y -= overlap * Math.sin(theta); 

    if (distance(ob1, ob2) < ob1.radius + ob2.radius) {
        // we don't want to be stuck in an infinite emergency.
        // so if we have already run one emergency round; just ignore the problem.
        if (!emergency) staticCollision(ob1, ob2, true)
    }
}

function moveObjects() {
    for (let i=0; i<objArray.length; i++) {
        let ob = objArray[i];
        ob.x += ob.dx * 1;
        ob.y += ob.dy * 1;
    }    
}

function drawObjects() {
    for (let obj in objArray) {
        objArray[obj].draw();
    }
}

let begin = true;
let temperature;

document.getElementById("temp").oninput = function()
{
    temperature = parseInt(document.getElementById("temp").value);
    console.log(temperature);
    generateBalls(temperature);
}

function draw() {
    
    /*currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    dt = (currentTime - lastTime) / 1000; // delta time in seconds
    
    // dirty and lazy solution
    // instead of scaling down every velocity vector
    // we decrease the speed of time
    dt *= 20;*/

    if(begin) {
        generateBalls(300);
        begin = false;
    }

    if (clearCanv) clearCanvas();
    canvasBackground();
    
    if (!paused) {
        moveObjects();
        ballCollision();
    }
    
    drawObjects();
    
    lastTime = currentTime;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

//work in progress
function setColor(vel)
{
    let red = 255, green = 255, blue = 255;
    let rc;
    green /= (vel * 0.001);
    blue /= (vel * 0.01);
    return rc = "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")";

}

let N = 300;
let m = 2.66e-26;
let T = 5;
let dV = 50;
let k = 1.38e-23;
let v = 50;
let balls;
let angolox;
let vel;
let color;


function generateBalls(T)
{
    v = 50;

    objArray = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < 39; i++) 
    { //each 50m/s, with dv = 50, until 2000m/s

    //molecules number between v and v+50
    probArray[i] = Math.floor(4 * Math.PI * N * (((m) / (2 * Math.PI * k * T))**1.5) * (v**2) * Math.exp((-m) / (2 * k * T) * (v**2)) * dV);
        v += 50;
    }

    v = 50;

    for(let i = 0; i < 39; i++)
    {
        let n = 0;
        balls = 0;
        while(n < probArray[i]) 
        {
            angolox = ((Math.random() * 360) * Math.PI) / 180; //converted in radians;
            vel = Math.round((Math.random() * 50) + v) / 160; 
            if(vel * 160 < 400)
                color = 'lightblue';
            else if(vel * 160 > 800)
                color = 'red';
            else
                color = 'orange';
            objArray[objArray.length] = new Ball(randomX(), randomY(), Math.cos(angolox) * vel, Math.sin(angolox) * vel, 5, color);
            balls++;
            n++;
        }
    v += 50;
    }
}

draw();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: khaki;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Ubuntu Mono;
  }

  #title {
    color: black;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 1px;
    border: 1px;
  }

  #balls {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }

  #myCanvas {
    margin-top: -20px;
  }

  section.footer {
    color: black;
    font-family: Ubuntu Mono;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: small;
  }
  #disclaimer {
    font-size: 74%;
    color: gray;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>2d collision</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gas.css">
</head>
<body style="text-align: center">
  
    <canvas onload="generateBalls()" id="myCanvas" width="1225%" height="500" style="border:1px solid black; margin-top: 10px;"></canvas>
  

    <p>
      <input type="range" min="1" max="2001" value="300" step="100" id="temp">
      <strong>[P]</strong>: pause/unpause || <strong>[R]</strong>: [RESET]
    </p>

    <div id="disclaimer" align="center" style="word-break: break-word; width: 350px; display:inline-block;">

      <p>
        Make sure to press a few buttons and play around.<br>Made with pure javascript.
      </p>

    </div>

  </section>
</body>
<script src="gas.js"></script>
</html>
```

Balls are generated with speeds(.dx) between 1 and 20, so they should be small enough not to cause that kind of lagging... but I'm still experiencing it. Any advice?? Have you got any "more efficient" animation solutions?

Comment: can you add a working snippet with HTML? that would make it easier to address the issue.

Comment: An immediate idea that comes to mind is that with 300 balls, when checking every ball against every other ball (inside `ballCollision`) thats 300² operations every frame. Also, I don't see any kind of check within `ballCollision` to see if the ball is 'colliding with itself'.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman ,uploaded full DHTML code

Comment: @dantechguy, sure, that's absolutely an inefficient one... but in my programming inexperience that's all I could have managed to think of, have you got other better solutions? And what do you mean with "colliding with itself"?

Comment: My bad, I didn't spot that your for loops counteract the 'double collisions' and 'colliding with itself'. I was concerned that `i` and `j` could have the same value. But a method you could use is to split the canvas up into an invisible grid, and then only check for ball collisions inside the same grid cell (eg nearby). This reminds me of a [fantastic video on Quadtrees](https://youtu.be/OJxEcs0w_kE).

Comment: @dantechguy That's really phenomenal also if not too easy. Definitely going to take a look at it! Thanks a lot